# Does MacBook Pro 13" 2017 and 2018 with Touch Bar have the same bandwidth on all 4 ports?

Tags: macos

I learnt from this article:

https://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/28/macbook-pro-tb3-reduced-pci-express-bandwidth/

...that the right ports on MacBook Pro 13" 2016 with Touchbar deliver reduced throughput for Thunderbolt devices.

I wonder if this is also the case with the 2017 and 2018 MacBook Pros.

Comment: Did the article explain what caused this? Was there contention with other devices or upstream / heat / other concerns? It’s best to bring the details from a link since we tend to keep questions and answers up for longer than many web links live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this information I found on an article:

> "The 13-inch MacBook Pro (2017) without Touch bar has 2x full-speed
>   Thunderbolt 3 ports / USB-C ports. The 13-inch MacBook Pro (2018) with
>   Touch ID has 4x Thunderbolt 3 / USB-C ports and, with the 2018 model,
>   all four of those ports are now full bandwidth."

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  It doesn't explicitly say if 2017 4 ports has reduced bandwidth on right ports, but it seems to mean it.

Comment: To answer to your comment, I found this in an article:

"2016 and 2017 models of the 13-inch MacBook Pro with Touch Bar could be configured with sixth- and seventh-generation Intel Core i5 and Core i7 processors, which supported up to 12 PCI Express lanes, limiting full speeds to the two left-side Thunderbolt 3 ports, with reduced bandwidth on the right-side ports."

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget to vote for my answer. ;-) Thx.

Comment: Of course mate!.  Oh! I never voted answers, thanks for letting me know.  What would I do without you folks.  I sometimes doubt on asking something lest I sound awkward.

Comment: Reminder Dakta - it seems odd to answer a question that you don’t also up vote. The only up vote on the question so far is me : ( Thanks to you both - good Q and A - especially if any details from the commends get edited into the body so when comments get deleted, the A and Q have all the details.